# How to request undeletion?

Tags: support, moderation, undelete-request

[One of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559449/keeping-a-header-always-in-view/4559679#4559679) was deleted by a mod today. I have since then corrected my answer and I would like to have it undeleted. I'm not able to do that myself, and there appears to be no explicit method to request undeletion. I can flag my answer but I'm not confident that all flags get processed. Ideally, I would like to be able to notify the mod who deleted my answer directly.

So what are my options here? I have flagged and I'm waiting for a response...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flagging your answer, explaining exactly what happened and why you think it should be undeleted is the right thing to do.

Any of the mods can understand your issue and deal with it, you don't have to contact the one that deleted your answer directly.

All the flags get processed eventually, just be patient.