# Request to undelete answer

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-answers, moderators

I wrote an answer to:  [What Applications Don't Need ACID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781542/what-applications-dont-need-acid)   which I put a lot of thought into.  However, this answer was deleted by Lasse Karlsen because I made the mistake of referencing my own company when trying to produce an example of "an application which doesn't need ACID" - the guy whose answer I was disagreeing with reported my answer as spam.

Can 3 moderators vote to undelete my answer?  (I've already clicked 'undelete' myself).

(Lasse says that posting here is the right procedure for getting an answer undeleted).

Comment: Why was referencing your company was a mistake/marked as spam? You aren't even in the business of producing DBs. And your company seems to be interested in a pretty limited market. I don't know how many persons on SO would be directly interested in buying your products.

Comment: It is undeleted now

Comment: It was flagged as spam, and I agreed, but I sent him here to get a second opinion. Marc disagreed, so all is well.

Comment: Right solution is here flag it to get moderator attention as per this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109469/how-to-request-undeletion

Answer (score 8):

I get ["a moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48929/can-a-user-undelete-an-answer-that-was-deleted-by-a-moderator) (I assume that means by 10k users, surely a diamond mod still can).

I wish I knew whether Lasse was sending you here to have the community judge whether it should be undeleted, or because he doesn't understand his diamond mod powers.

Apparently the feature was implemented in ignorance of [this excellent request to simply increase the number of undelete votes needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77380/users-should-not-be-able-to-undelete-answers-deleted-by-a-moderator)

And Shog9 [suggests that the flag affects our ability to undelete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60717/question-owner-able-to-undelete-question-that-was-not-self-deleted/60722#60722), although he was talking about questions, I think flags work the same for answers.

Comment: I did in fact send him here to get a second opinion, I also said he could flag the answer again, and I would stay clear. I still think the original handling of the spam flags was correct, it was an old question and to me the answer read a lot like the other long answer there, except that it seemed to boast his company a lot. So I deleted it. Marc disagreed, it was undeleted, and that's that.

Answer (score 2):

As the answer was deleted from a moderator, I think it is better to flag the answer for moderation attention, and ask to undelete the question because it was not your intention to spam. When an answer is deleted from a moderator, it can be undeleted just from another moderator; the post doesn't require three different moderators, as moderator's votes are blinding, which means they have immediate effect.
Clearly, the moderator who deleted the answer should avoid to mark the flag as invalid, and leave to somebody else the decision about the answer being spam, or not.

It could also help if you rewrite the answer to avoid adding the incriminated link.